# How to validata user by cookie when send POST request to backend Next.js - Next-Auth?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

What I trying to do:

I have a post that users can comment on anything they want by sending to Backend content, userId, postId. Everything working fine BUT:
Someone, they know your userId they can use Postman or something same and send to my BE. That's not good!

I see some sites sending cookies and validating in the backend? How can I do that ?
By the way, I using Next-auth.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a backend (server) that stores the different users with their data and uses some sort of authentication to let particular users access to the services, based on their login credentials.